# Edit that remove the entire code of a question

Tags: discussion, edits

[Get the Last Modified date of an URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7999258/get-the-last-modified-date-of-an-url) recently had an edit that strip all the code from the question. I'm pretty sure this is not a thing to do since now the question make no sense at all. What is the good action to take ? Should I rollback the edit?

Comment: I'd go with "Yes".

Comment: Yes is the answer; I've done it already for ya ;)

Comment: Thanks @AndrewBarber I was wondering if there is something else to do in this case, like warning the op or something.

Comment: Incidentally, that was not the only one. I'm fixing them all now.

Comment: "temporarily suspended to cool down"? Is that one of the predefined messages, or is it custom?

Comment: @Old Checkmark: Predefined. Of course, the message that actually gets sent to them is more elaborate and specific.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Rolling back a single 'bad' edit like this is appropriate.

If you notice the user rolling back to the 'bad' edit, or if you see a number of such edits, the best thing to do is to flag for moderator attention using "other" and explain the situation. It's best not to get into an editing war.

If you don't have enough reputation to do a non-reviewed edit, you won't see a Rollback option in the editing history. In that case, you can simply flag for a moderator. It's usually not practical to try to do a manual edit in such a case.

(You were not engaged in such an 'editing war', but I wanted to add that for future readers)

Comment: Is it normal that I didn't see the "rollback" link?

Comment: @Marc-Andre Ahhh; you don't have enough reputation to do normal edits, so the Rollback link won't show up for you. In that case, a simple moderator flag will do.